# Audio Fingerprinting: Can I find out the exact audio time code with tools such as Echoprint or AcusticID?

Tags: audio, audio-fingerprinting, echonest

I understand that landmark based fingerprinting uses time and frequency, but can I get the time code of landmarks / the offset as an output using open source tools? Or something else to sync some content with audio?